# NHibernate IDataBaseSchema.GetTableMetadata method take a datarow. How can I use this method?

Tags: database, sqlite, nhibernate, schema, hbm2ddl

I'm trying to verify a table gets created. I'm using SQLite and NHibernate.

```
new SchemaExport(_configuration)
            .Execute(true, true, false, _session.Connection, Console.Out);


IDataBaseSchema dbMeta = new SQLiteDataBaseMetaData((DbConnection) _session.Connection);
ITableMetadata tbMeta = dbMeta.GetTableMetadata(//where do I get the datarow this method needs?, and what are the extras args?);
```

How can I use this method correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you verify that your mappings and your DB schema are in synch (See [SchemaValidator](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/22/nhibernate-schemavalidator.aspx)); that should do the trick.